# How to show placeholder in different lines in Text Input?

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput whith `multiline={true}`. I want to know how to get its placeholder text like:

```
Hey There!
Want any Help?
Placeholder To The Rescue!
```

I tried some like `placeholder='Hey There!\nWant any Help?'` but didn't get what i wanted.

I'm sort of new to React Native. Helps would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found An Answer! Using braces made it render what I wanted. I figured out that React Native renders strings here as it is, but with the formatting given, if inside braces. For eg:

```
<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  placeholder='Hey There!\nHow are You?'
/>
```

With the above code rendered, the TextInput will look like:

```
HeyThere!\nHow are You?
```

But if you use braces like this:

```
<TextInput
  multiline={true}
  placeholder={'Hey There!\nHow are You?'}
/>
```

Then You will get the TextInput like:

```
Hey There!
How are You?
```

And That's Exactly what I wanted!

**Well, Thank You Folks for Replying!**

Answer (score 1):

```
  <TextInput
    multiline={true}
    placeholder={'Hey There! \nWant any Help? \nPlaceholder To The Rescue!'}
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1,fontSize:12}}

  />
```

[image: screenshot of the solution you are looking for]

Comment: I want to get it's placeholder to look like what I've given above. Adding numberOfLines prop didn't give me that. It just sets a limit to the number of lines of input that can be accepted, right?

Comment: 'Hey There! \nWant any Help? \nPlaceholder To The Rescue!'   and give a fontsize of 12

Comment: Copying your edited code did get me a multi-line placeholder. But how did decreasing the font size make the placeholder multi-line?

Comment: decreased the font size to align the last line of placeholder text in a single line as you need.

Comment: Well, I found that the braces' absence while giving the props' value was the real reason here.

Comment: malayali spotted :p

Comment: Kochu Kallan! ;-)

Comment: evdeya vdu .kozhikode?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `textarea` html tag.That allow you to do multiline placeholder.

Comment: I'm working with React Native. Can I get it's TextInput's placeholder to render HTML tags? I don't think so....

Comment: oh sorry i do not saw you need it for react native.I don't know it because i do not use react native